# App doing opposite of what checkbox is supposed to do

Tags: java, android, checkbox

I'm in the middle of making an app and I'm running into a road block.
Basically I have a checkbox... If the checkbox is checked, it is supposed enable the entry of text in an edit text preference, and use that value. But here's where the problem lies... If the box is unchecked it uses the value in the EditTextPreference. If the box is checked, it uses the hard coded value.

Part of my activity:

```
private void loadURI()
  {
      PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.settings, true);
      SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
      if (settings.getBoolean("default_uri", false)){
            String defaultURI = getString(R.string.dream_uri);
            this.mWebView.loadUrl(defaultURI);
      }
      else {
          String customURI = settings.getString("custom_uri", "");
          this.mWebView.loadUrl(customURI);
      }

  }
```

Settings.xml:

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="Backdrop Settings" >
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:title="Use Custom Backdrop URL"
            android:id="@id/checkBox1"
            android:key="default_uri"
            android:defaultValue="true"/>
        <EditTextPreference
            android:title="Custom Backdrop URL"
            android:summary="Tap here to enter custom URL"
            android:id="@id/editText1"
            android:defaultValue="Enter Custom URL here"
            android:key="custom_uri"
            android:dependency="default_uri" />
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:title="Use a Custom Slideshow Period?"
            android:key="slide_duration"
            android:defaultValue="false"/>
        <ListPreference
            android:title="Slideshow Duration"
            android:summary="How long should each slide be displayed?"
            android:key="list_duration"
            android:dependency="slide_duration"/>
    </PreferenceCategory>
    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="Other">
        <Preference
            android:title="Test Dream"
            android:summary="Tap here to test the dream"
            android:key="testDream" />
        <Preference
            android:title="About"
            android:key="AboutApp"
            android:summary="About this app" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

And my Preferences activity:

```
public class mollySettings extends PreferenceActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);

        Preference button = findPreference("testDream");
        button.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference arg0) {
                final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                intent.setClassName("com.android.systemui", "com.android.systemui.Somnambulator");
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            }
        });

        Preference about = findPreference("AboutApp");
        about.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference arg1) {
                final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                intent.setClassName("com.death2all110.flogging.molly", "com.death2all110.flogging.molly.About");
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            }
        });


    }
}
```

Thanks in advance, and please let me know if there is anything else you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it figured out.

I added an exclamation point to the if statement. So the loadURI method is now:

```
private void loadURI()
  {
      PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.settings, true);
      SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
      if (!settings.getBoolean("default_uri", false)){
            String defaultURI = getString(R.string.dream_uri);
            this.mWebView.loadUrl(defaultURI);
      }
      else {
          String customURI = settings.getString("custom_uri", "");
          this.mWebView.loadUrl(customURI);
      }

  }
```

Instead of:

```
private void loadURI()
  {
      PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.settings, true);
      SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
      if (settings.getBoolean("default_uri", false)){
            String defaultURI = getString(R.string.dream_uri);
            this.mWebView.loadUrl(defaultURI);
      }
      else {
          String customURI = settings.getString("custom_uri", "");
          this.mWebView.loadUrl(customURI);
      }

  }
```